# Why my cron is not executed on the remote linux?

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have below scripts as php file and want to execute this in CRON. It works in local but when I go remote linux it fails.

```
<?php
    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;
    $b = $a + $b;
    echo 'TEST-SUM'.$b;
    //echo substr("Hello world!",6);
    //echo 'Test Cron Job On Mturk!';
?>
```

1) The above one works in this way of execution in REMOTE server.

```
php test.php
```

2) But not using the following cron syntax:

```
* * * * * php /home/www/cronjob/test.php 2>&1 >> /home/test/www/cronjob/createhitlog.log
```

I am trying to check whether CRON is working on the REMOTE server or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem confused about *remote* and *local*.

This would be running it locally:

```
php test.php
```

This would be an example of running it remotely with a cron:

```
* * * * * curl --silent http://www.yoursite.com/cronjob/test.php
```

Of course this remote usage implies security implications that you'd need to address.

Comment: I agree. I'm also confused a little by the question.

Answer (score 1):

If this doesn't work in [CRON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), I bet it's the users access rights and permissions.

1. Check if the [CRON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) user is allowed to start php together with this script.
2. Check if the [CRON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) user is allowed to write into (or create) the createhitlog.log-file.

Comment: Just found the hyperlink button eh? Yeah it's pretty fun.

Comment: Indeed! But it also helps to link to pretty useful resources.